# Chrome app offline mode

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Hi good day anyone have tutorial how to make my chrome extension/app offline?

I'm new on developing chrome apps I just embed my website url to my manifest.json but i want my chrome app usable even offline mode
anyone have tutorial on how to make chrome app offline?

Answer (score 3):

Use ["offline_enabled": true](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/offline_enabled) in manifest.json and read [Offline First](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_apps).

Comment: Just adding `"offline_enabled": true` does not do much to a Chrome App or Extension. As per [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/offline_enabled), all it does it highlight the app in `chrome://extensions` when the computer is offline.

Comment: I think he uses webview. For webview we must use "offline_enabled": true.

Comment: "most cases" in your answer is not the best option in this case. Just use "offline_enabled": true and don't think about the default values. Anyway the app of course needs to be able to load some resources from the local store. But I think that is another question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why must `offline_enabled` be true for apps that use webview? Considering that OP explicitly asks about "how to make my chrome extension/app offline," I think it's appropriate to provide some direction about the data persistence interfaces that Chrome Apps expose. As I referenced before in the documentation, simply setting the `offline_enabled` manifest key does not magically turn a Chrome App into an offline app.

Comment: Magically :) Anyway, we have given links to the documentation. I think we helped him.

Comment: Than you for your suggestions I try the offline_enabled:true but still can connect when i take actions.

But thanks for the reference for how make an offline mode using chrome apps I hope I can make my project :)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand currently (Chrome 47), there might be a issue with webviews and offline support. In fact as soon as you include a webview, by default the offline_enabled flag gets set to false.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/offline_enabled

Now theoretically the only way a webview is going to work offline is if its content is cached. Ergo you would think to use the HTML5 Application Cache.

If you have a Chrome OS device that is disconnected from the Internet but running an app with a webview, even if you explicitly set the offline_enabled flag back to true and your webview wants to load content that you have in your HTML5 Application Cache it seems this scenario does not work right now.

Simply having a webview, even one that is going to load a HTML5 app/page  completely from the HTML5 Application Cache, Chrome OS will give you an ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED error before trying to load the URL.

Oddly enough, if your HTML5 Application Cache has completely cached the app/page and the server of the URL is offline BUT your Chrome OS device is connected to the Internet, the webview will correctly load up the page from the HTML5 App Cache.

I brought this issue up to Google today. It seems to be an oversight with the webviews and failure to check the HTML5 Application Cache when the device is offline. I will update here if anyone is interested.

---

Feb 3, 2016 EDIT

We figured out our problem was our app originally tries a http URL which gets redirected to https and then cached. When we are offline, it only tries http and fails to find anything cached so we get the dinosaur page offline.

By trying https only in our case, everything works. webviews with AppCache work fine in Chrome OS apps in offline.

Answer (score 1):

Making a Chrome App work offline takes more than adding `"offline_enabled": true` to your `manifest.json`. Indeed, in most cases the `offline_enabled` setting is [`true` by default](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/offline_enabled).

What offline means is that most, if not all, of your application's data is stored locally on a computer running the app. That way, the app does not care whether it is connected to the Internet. Check out [this link](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_apps) from the Chrome App developer site. You'll also want to take a look at the [Chrome `storage` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage) to download, sync, and manage your data.